# How to solve for the angle of an arc in this circumstance?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is a shape I came upon during work (3D modelling), and I have been trying to figure out how to better describe it.

The shape is comprised of four equal arcs of a circle, such that the radius of each arc is the distance between their midpoints, and the origin of each arc is the midpoint of the arc opposite:

[image]

How to I determine the angle of the arc, $\theta$? I know from playing around graphically that $\theta\approx48.59°$, but I would love to know how to actually solve for it. It should be noted that $\theta$ is a constant, and is independent of the radius $r$.

Comment: In terms of construction, this is just two circles of equal radius such that each center is on the other's edge, then the overlap shape is rotated 90 degrees about the midpoint of the segment joining the circles' centers.

Comment: Also, note that because of the construction the angle is independent of the noted radius.

Comment: That's a good point. The shape above can be constructed with any given radius r, but it will always require the same angle θ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the triangle formed by the centers of two adjacent arcs and their intersection point. It has sides $r,r,\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$(To see that the third side is $\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$, let the tangents to to the arcs at their respective midpoints meet at $A,B,C,D$, it is easy to see that they form a square and the side of the square is $r$. The line joining the two centers of the arcs is the line joining the midpoint of two adjacent sides of the square and its length is obviously $\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$!) and one of the two equal angles of the triangle is $\frac{\theta}{2}+45^{\circ}$(This is by symmetry). In the isosceles triangle in consideration, simple trigonometry yields $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}+45^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Now $$-\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta+90^{\circ})=\cos(2\cdot(\frac{\theta}{2}+45^{\circ}))=2(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}})^2-1=\frac{-3}{4}$$ $$\implies \sin(\theta)=\frac{3}{4} \implies \theta=\arcsin(\frac{3}{4})\approx 48.59^{\circ}$$ Just to make things clearer, here is the diagram: $IEG$ is the triangle in consideration.

[image]

Comment: Nicely done!  I hadn't gotten to that one piece of the correct triangle to evaluate.  +1

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**
$$\theta=(2\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}-90)^\circ\approx 48.6^\circ.$$

**Proof:**

[image]

Firstly, it is clear that $ABCD$ is a square.

By resolving, we find that $HE=r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$, and so $EF=r-r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$.

By symmetry, this means that $GH=EF=r-r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. This in turn means that the length of each side of the square - given by $AB$ and is also given by $EG$- can be written as  $$AB=EG=r-2(r-r\cos\frac{\theta}{2})=2r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-r.$$

However, we can also write $AB$ in a different way:

$$AB=2AE=2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}.$$
Equating our two expressions for $AB$:

$$\begin{align}&2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=2r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-r\\
\implies &\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\implies &\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\\
\implies&\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+45^\circ\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\\
\implies&\frac{\theta}{2}+45^\circ=\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\\
\implies & \theta=(2\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}-90)^\circ.\end{align}$$